# Has anyone ever acknowledged this interpretation of the name of the Galactica?

Tags: names, battlestar-galactica

Before Edwin Hubble discovered the true distance to objects such as the Andromeda "Nebula", it was widely believed that all the stars in the universe were contained within the Milky Way, which was named for its appearance in the night sky as a light-colored band resembling a swath of spilled milk. Hence, from the Greek *galaktikos* meaning "milky", we arrived at the Latin *galaxias* and *galacticus* and the modern words "galaxy" and "galactic"<sup>[[1]](http://ttps://www.etymonline.com/word/galaxy)</sup>.

I have never seen an episode of *Battlestar Galactica* in any of its incarnations; everything I know of the franchise has been adsorbed indirectly through videos discussing and comparing multiple science fiction universes. Nonetheless, given that the fan wiki doesn't include an alternative explanation, I feel safe in assuming that the titular spacecraft's name is derived from the modern word "galactic."

While "galactic" would never be used this way today, and hasn't for over a hundred years, I can't help but laugh at the thought of fighting an interstellar war in a ship whose name could be interpreted as meaning "milky." I know it's a long shot, but has any character in the show(s) ever acknowledged this, even for a quick joke? "No use crying over spilled milk" after taking damage, etc?

The alternative is that my sense of humor is distorted beyond hope of repair. I concede that this is a substantial possibility.

Comment: I guess that kind of trivia really sticks with you? :D

Comment: In-Universe, it doesn't make much sense. But naming what is essentially an aircraft carrier with a diverse crew (in Space!) after some worthy person of the Republic wouldn't tell TV watchers that this is Star Wars on TV. ("Battlestar Ronald McCain" does not sound like much fun). P.S. I just checked [Criticism and legal action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Galactica_(1978_TV_series)#Criticism_and_legal_actions). The "everything is mine" attitude of the studios sucks. Akira Kurosawa should have known that he could sue Lucasfilm for billions.

Comment: No idea, but I never knew Galaxy came from "Milky". Galaktikos sounds like Lactose too, which is the sugar found in mammalian milk apparently. Interesting. P.S. My Galaxy chocolate bar now makes more sense to me.